# Scrapy crawler pagination for indeed website

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class SearchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'search'
    allowed_domains = ['www.indeed.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20analyst&l=united%20states']

    def parse(self, response):
        listings = response.xpath('//*[@data-tn-component="organicJob"]')
        for listing in listings:
            title = listing.xpath('.//a[@data-tn-element="jobTitle"]/@title').extract_first()
            link = listing.xpath('.//h2[@class="title"]//a/@href').extract_first()
            company = listing.xpath('normalize-space(.//span[@class="company"]//a/text())').extract_first()

            yield {'title':title,
            'link':link,
            'company':company}
            
        next_page = response.xpath('//ul[@class="pagination-list"]//a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page),callback=self.parse)
```

I am trying to extract all the job titles and company for every job posting in all the indeed pages. However, I am stuck at a point, because the forward button on the indeed page does not have a fixed link which my scraper could follow instead the next page url is the same as the numbered button. Which means that even after requesting the next page url, the numbers at the end change which does not allow me to extract the next page. I am trying to refrain from using selenium or splash, since I am trying to get my results through only Scrapy or Beautifull Soup. However, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not using the url pagination instead ? `https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=united+states&start=10`/`20`/`30` ...

Comment: I am not sure how the url pagination with scrapy would look like. Does the url pagination feed into the request part of scrapy?

Comment: Could I complete this through the rule and link extractor? could the link extractor follow the next link with different numbers on the next page?